# How to trim MongoDB aggregate result's one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is my data structure store in DB

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58a4e451c164f95c98e96235"),
    "_class" : "com.contix.log.parser.log.Log",
    "vin" : "6",
    "esn" : "c",
    "volt" : 11.32,
    "internVolt" : 4.14,
    "temp" : 39.49,
    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1483375743285")
}
```

What I want to do is get latest 10 unique volt, internVolt, temp based on vin and esn String. Also needs latest timestamp. Then I'm trying to use mongo aggregate way to get right result.

```
db.log.aggregate({$sort:{timestamp:-1}},{$group:{_id : {esn:"$esn",vin:"$vin"},firstTimestamp:{$first:"$timestamp"},volts:{$addToSet:"$volt"}}},{$limit:5})
```

But this is my result looks like

> { "_id" : { "esn" : "b", "vin" : "2" }, "firstTimestamp" :
>   NumberLong("1485852368147"), "volts" : [ 11.95, 10.08, 10.77, 10.47,
>   11.41, 10.36, 10.96, 10.75, 10.39, 10.53, 10.1, 10.22, 11.16, 10.11, 11.87, 11.33, 11.82, 11.78, 10.25, 11.86, 10.5, 10.41, 11.3, 11.31, 11.97, 10.64, 11.57, 10.93, 10.02, 10.68, 10.9, 11.53, 10.46, 11.42, 11.73, 11.32, 10.19, 10.51, 11.35, 11.28, 10.65, 10.21, 11.18, 10.91, 11.43, 10.52, 11.34, 11.1, 10.99, 10.61, 10.28, 10.97, 10.3, 10.31, 11.81, 11.8, 10.42, 11.51, 10.72, 11.39, 10.69, 11.27, 11.11, 10.15, 10.78, 10.58, 11.49, 10.94, 11.64, 10.32, 11.63, 10.03, 10.81, 11.83, 10.82, 11.84, 10.79, 10.66, 11.21, 10.24, 11.75, 11.2 ] }

And other 4 similar stuff.

I don't know if there is any way that can trim $volts this kind data int group pipeline. The $limit or $skip operation seems use for whole documents.

My dream result should look like below.

> { "_id" : { "esn" : "b", "vin" : "2" }, "firstTimestamp" :
>   NumberLong("1485852368147"), "volts" : [ 10.81, 11.83, 10.82, 11.84, 10.79, 10.66, 11.21, 10.24, 11.75, 11.2 ], "innerVolts":[...], "temp":[...] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to trim the results, you can use projection and do something like this:

```
db.log.aggregate([
         {$sort:{timestamp:-1}},
         {$group:{
                  _id : {esn:"$esn",vin:"$vin"},
                 firstTimestamp:{$first:"$timestamp"},
                 volts:{$addToSet:"$volt"},
                 innerVolts:{$addToSet:"$innerVolt"},
                 temp:{$addToSet:"$temp"}                     
          }},
          { $project: {
               _id:1,
               firstTimestamp:1,
               volts: {$slice : ["$volts",10]},
               innerVolts: {$slice : ["$innerVolts",10]}, 
               temp: {$slice:["$temp",10]}
           }}])
```

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: I know this. I just wanna get volts last ten elements.

Comment: I think I got your problem. Please, check my edition.

Comment: Is there any possible that I slice last 10 element not first 10? Because I found last ten elements is the latest 10. I think addToSet may keep a link list.

Comment: Do you know how to map this project operation to Spring Mongo template? When I use  project(Fields...) I type project("id", "firstTimestamp", "volts"). But it seems I should add $slice into volts...I don't have more quota to ask another question...

Comment: Sorry man, I've never used Spring Mongo. Usually I use nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) modifier to trim the array to the lastest N items.

Comment: Thanks, I've figure out this. But when I map the query to JAVA I met a new problem that is the ProjectionOperation don't have slice this kind of methods. So I don't know if you know this problem. I don't have quota to ask more question- - life is so tough...

Comment: MongoDB do support projection operator $slice. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/). Probably problem with the JAVA library you are using.